# Proguard fails with InterruptedException: Too many errors

Tags: android, proguard

Proguard - so I assume - fails with the following Exception(s): `java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors`. Strange thing is: no errors show up in the log. The closest thing to an error seems to be some notes Icepick is logging on Error-Level and warnings on deprecation:

`14:01:49.568 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: IcepickProcessor took 55 milliseconds
14:01:50.367 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: IcepickProcessor took 0 milliseconds
14:01:50.848 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: IcepickProcessor took 0 milliseconds
14:01:53.195 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
14:01:53.195 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14:01:53.195 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
14:01:53.195 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`

Is ProGuard or Gradle misjudging these notes as actual errors?

Comment: can you use --info or -debug on the build in order to get more details?

Comment: Already did. But the resulting file is about 10MB total. Any recommendations how to make this file available?